# Cannot connect csv to Excel thru ODBC

Tags: excel, connection, odbc

HI;
I cannot connect a CSV file to a SpreadSheet when the file is open. Currently a have a csv log file that is being constantly updated. I was able to connect it a an Excel SpreadSheet by normal import from external source with refresh every hour. However, its a big file so I needed to produce the reports using EXCEL SQL. It will not allow me to connect to the file while it is open. It says that the MS Jet database engine cannot open the file'unknown'. It is already opened exclusively by another user or i need permission to view its data. If granting permission is he problem , where do I grant myself permission. On a standard Impor, I have no problems reading the file while it is open, but otherwise, get this message and cannot proce3ed. Any help would be appreciated. If I close the update program, I am able to run the queries, but not if the update  is running.
 Using MSO 2007 W7 x64

Answer (score 0):

> It will not allow me to connect to the file while it is open.

That's right, it won't - there is no way to change this.

You must find another way to solve your problem.

1. How big is the file? You may be able to make a copy to a temporary filename, and connect Excel to that instead.
2. It sounds like you are accessing a logfile. **LogParser** can read CSV. In any case LogParser has an excellent SQL-like syntax and can read CSV files much more quickly and reliably than ODBC. It is also programmable from Excel VBA (or script). Perhaps you can use LogParser to extract the values of interest and then load those into your Excel table instead.

I suspect your best solution will be to use the LogParser `MSUtil.LogQuery` object from Excel VBA, to extract the values of interest into your spreadsheet. Since I don't know what you are actually doing this is just a guess!

I cannot recommend LogParser highly enough - it is a wonderful tool, and can read just about every standard type of logfile, CSV, TSV, W3C, as well as plain text files and the windows NT event logs:

- LogParser 2.2 Download: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en

Comment: Thanks for your response. Will I be able to read this file through MSUTIL.LoqQuery while it is open and return the result set to my Excel SpreadSheet?

Comment: Probably: If you can open it in notepad, then yes. It depends on the "share mode" it was opened with. If it was opened without `SHARE_DENY_READ` flag (which it probably was), you will be fine. On the other hand, if it was opened `SHARE_DENY_READ` then no standard tool will be able to open it since that's what the flag means.